# Shipping Methods disappear

Tags: shipping, ups, usps

I configured my shopping cart to have 4 types of options for shipping:
free delivery, store pick up, usps, and ups.

Every so often when checking out either usps or ups disappears.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Any chance the endpoint cant be connected?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: USPS or UPS webservice not available or not reachable.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. Because when I refresh it then both show up again.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be a checkout/extn issue, or network related issue with your magento install. UPS and USPS are extremely reliable, I've never seen a problem where they randomly do not return rates back.

If you have a non-standard checkout I'd be looking there first.

Answer (score 0):

There can be varied issues associated with this problem. UPS might be disappearing due to following -

**Network issue with your connection with the UPS web services.**

Make sure you are able to connect to the UPS web services properly. Also make sure that the UPS web service is not currently facing any downtime issues at the moment.

**Product Configuration**

Ensure that you have assigned proper weight to the product which is lower than the maximum weight accepted by shipping carrier (UPS in this case).

Enable the "Show Method If Not Applicable" and "Debugging" from the admin panel to get error/response in log files.
[image]

Then check your *var* folder.

Hope this helps :)